# How to get the MongoClient when using embedmongo-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven

The question is that if I use [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) to do the unit test.I could get the MongoClient by :

```
 private static MongodForTestsFactory testsFactory;
 private MongoClient mongo;
 ...
 testsFactory=MongodForTestsFactory.with(Version.Main.PRODUCTION);
 mongo = testsFactory.newMongo();
```

But if I use the plugin [embedmongo-maven-plugin](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/embedmongo-maven-plugin) to do the same thing.I don't know how to get the mongoClient to do the unit test.In other words,there maybe no need to get the MongoClient? I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: here is a great example that you can refer to https://github.com/joelittlejohn/embedmongo-maven-plugin

Comment: I used exactly this,but after add the Usage to the pom.xml,I don't know how to write in the java code,in another word,I can`t get the MongoClient to test the use case.

Comment: you dont need a mongoclient. did your test class extends MongoScriptsMojo  ? if yes then you need to pass the connection details to the super class. this(dataFolder, port, databaseName, new EmbedMongoDB("myDB"), scriptCharsetEncoding); look at the code here http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=embedmongo-maven-plugin-master/src/main/java/com/github/joelittlejohn/embedmongo/MongoScriptsMojo.java